# cardano-db-sync error

Tags: cardano-db-sync

When following the instruction here
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/blob/master/doc/building-running.md
I get an error at the last line

```
PGPASSFILE=config/pgpass-mainnet db-sync-node/bin/cardano-db-sync \
    --config /home/user/relay/mainnet-config.yaml \
    --socket-path /home/user/relay/node.socket \
    --state-dir /home/user/relay/db \
    --schema-dir schema/
```

the error is

```
FatalError {fatalErrorMessage = "readSyncNodeConfig: Error parsing config: AesonException \"Error in $: key \\\"NetworkName\\\" not found\""}
```

Any any help or direction is appreaciated. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are using the right [config file](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/blob/master/config/mainnet-config.yaml). The error is indicating that the config file you are using does not have the NetworkName parameter.

Comment: how do I determine if it is the right one? its the one that comes default with cardano-node latest release repo.

Comment: I linked the proper one in my answer. You need the config for db-sync not cardano-node

Comment: thank you that was pretty dumb of me for not check for that file name ....

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a db-sync config file, not a cardano-node one. You can get the correct configuration file for mainnet/testnet networks here: https://hydra.iohk.io/build/8111119/download/1/index.html. That link is found in the cardano-node release notes under `downloads -> configuration files`